# iOS: is it possible to create a matrix of NSObjects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, matrix, memory-leaks

Since objective C is a superset of C it' possible to use malloc/free with primitive types to create a matrix of NxM elements. I wouldn't like it because it may cause bugs and memory leaks. This last point is still true? Do ARC provide releasing of C types?

```
 int** matrix=(int**)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
     matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
```

Is it possible another Objective-C way? I found NSMatrix but it's for mac, not iOS.

Comment: the posted code has some problems.  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() and family of functions to assure the operation was successful

Comment: thanks for the note :) but that wasn't the subject that interested me, it was just a simple code without any check.
I made an explicit cast after malloc because C++ compiler requires that, so doing this way I can reuse the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do ARC provide releasing of C types?

No, it does not. ARC stands for *Automated Reference Counting*, meaning that it works only with reference-counted objects.

Since `malloc`/`free` deals with "plain" freestore allocations, memory blocks that you receive from `malloc` are not eligible for ARC.

This does not mean, however, that you couldn't achieve some degree of automation in managing `malloc`-allocated memory by "piggybacking" on ARC:

- Make your own class that has an instance variable pointing to your matrix, and allocate the matrix in the designated initializer.
- Add `dealloc` method that calls `free` on the allocated memory blocks.

Now you have a reference-counted class that holds your matrix. Whenever ARC instructs your class to deallocate, the memory held by the matrix gets released as well:

```
@interface Matrix : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int** data;
-(instancetype)initiWithRows:(NSUInteger)rows andColumns:(NSUInteger)cols;
-(void)dealloc;
@end
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I hope they will give us NStype for matrices